# Dynamic array with new in c++ - cout array[num]

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I am trying to diplay the value stored inside the array but only the value of`array[0] = 13;` is shown. For `array[1] = 4;` it prints out an adress. I read the introduction of new but that doesnt helped. What is wrong?

````
std::cin >> _size; //_size > 2
int* array;
         array = new int[_size];
         array[0] = 13;
         array[1] = 4; 

         std::cout << array[0] << std::endl;
         std::cout << array[1] << std::endl;```

console output:
13
0000008CFCF5F518
````

Comment: What does _size contain? Show the entire code

Comment: Anything > 2 in my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is weird, try this code and compare it to your entire code, you will understand:

```
int *array;
unsigned _size;
std::cin>>_size;
array=new int[_size];
array[0]=13;
array[1]=4;
std::cout<<array[0]<<'\n';
std::cout<<array[1];
delete[]array;
```

Comment: This works... but still trying to understand... but at the moment im fine. thanks.